# What is difference between Route object and AS-SET object in RIRs?

Tags: routing, routing-registry

In what case,we need to create AS-SET objects in RIRs.

If i have to advertise a prefix from different ASNs in different region,do I need to create as-set object?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

A `route:`  object should include an `origin: AS<x>` attribute associating the route with its BGP origin AS.  You can **create multiple route objects** to announce the same prefix from multiple ASNs.

An `as-set:`  has a different use.  If you have downstream ASNs, you may list them all in an as-set: then tell your transit providers & peers about your as-set.  This saves you from having to inform them about each ASN -- helpful if your network is big enough that the list of downstream ASNs changes frequently (new customers, etc).

If you have multiple ASNs you use in different locations, you might consider listing all your ASNs in an `as-set:`  to simplify your transit providers' jobs when provisioning.

Comment: Thanks.  From your answer I can understand that, We can either have multiple route objects or a single as-set object (with all the ASNs) to advertise a prefix from a multiple AS. Please correct me if Im wrong.

Comment: You should have multiple `route:` objects.  You **may also** create an `as-set:` listing all your ASNs.  This can help your transit providers & peers.  No matter what, though, create a route: for each prefix-to-ASN association.